# NUMBER(10,2) in oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, type-conversion

Inside oracle database variable data type is `NUMBER(10,2)`. So I need to get this value inside my java code. I tried with different ways:

- `Float`
- `float`
- `double`
- `Double`
- `BigDecimal`

But these thing not mapping in java. What I need to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try BigDecimal setting scale.
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

Comment: @RaheelaAslam what is the d

Comment: d is the actual value that comes from database.

Comment: @RaheelaAslam Why would you set scale to 10, when data type in Oracle database has a scale of 2? Why would you even set it? It'll already be 2 when read from database, and it will be rounded for you (if needed) when inserted/updated in database).

Comment: Sorry my Bad actually we have to set 2.
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

Answer (score 1):

Use [ResultSet.getBigDecimal(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal(int)) to get by index

or [ResultSet.getBigDecimal(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal(java.lang.String)) to get by column name

This is also recommended in [JDBC Guide](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html) for any Numeric type

> JDBC Types Mapped to Java Types
>
> NUMERIC    java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double` or `BigDecimal`.

Example, assuming table `ATEST` with column `N` defined as `CREATE TABLE ATEST (  N NUMBER(10,2)  )`:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OraNum {
    private static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:sid";
    private static String user = "User";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var pwd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password: ");
        if (pwd == null) {
            return;
        }

        try (
                var conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
                var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select N from ATEST");
                var rset = stmt.executeQuery();
                ) {
            while (rset.next()) {
                double d = rset.getDouble(1);
                BigDecimal big = rset.getBigDecimal(1);
                System.out.printf("double: %s,  BigDecimal: %s%n", d, big);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `rset.getObject()` to get an Object. Checking its class you will see what the driver returns for that type (`BigDecimal` here); `getDouble()` just converts it to `double` - this may cause some precision lost, so is is probably better to use `BigDecimal`. (same true for `getInt`)

Note: `rset.getString()` would also work, returning the textual representation (`String`) of the number.

Comment: BTW above code is a [mcve] (well, almost minimal, I didn't want to include the password)